# the "width" property of <pre> doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html

I use the "width" property of pre to control the maximum number of words each line. In firefox it performs normally, but in Chrome the "width" property  doesn't work. I don't know why.

for example: width=70

Comment: That makes perfect sense; `<pre>` tags don't have a `width` property.  You need CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` attribute for `pre` was originally defined in [HTML 2.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.5.2) as follows: “The WIDTH attribute specifies the maximum number of characters for a line and allows the HTML user agent to select a suitable font and indentation.” So it was not meant to change the basic meaning of `pre` (preserving whitespace and line breaks, with no added wrapping). This was retained in newer specifications, but not implemented in browsers.

Firefox instead treats `width` as indicating the character limit after which text wraps. Other browsers ignore it.

To specify wrapping, set `width` in CSS and set `white-space: pre-wrap` (widely supported in reasonably new browsers). But ask yourself: if you don’t want the basic effect of `pre` (preserving formatting as is), should you be using some other element?

You cannot set `width` in characters in CSS, but using the [`ch` unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/length) works well in supporting browsers, if the font is monospace (which is the default for `pre`). For older browsers, you might use the `em` unit, using some rough guess on the width of characters in the font to be used. Example:

```
pre { 
white-space: pre-wrap;
width: 40em;
width: 70ch;
}
```

If you instead wish to reduce font size, as per the original idea of `<pre width=...>`, set `font-size` on the `pre` element.

Answer (score 1):

From the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4):

> width = number [CN]
>   Deprecated. This attribute provides a hint to visual user agents about the desired width of the formatted block. The user agent can use this information to select an appropriate font size or to indent the content appropriately. The desired width is expressed in number of characters. **This attribute is not widely supported currently**.

HTML 5 marks the attribute as [obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete) and says:

> The following attributes are obsolete (though the elements are still part of the language), and **must not be used by authors**
>   …
>   width on pre elements

If you want to control the width, do so in CSS. You can't, unfortunately, specify it in *characters*.

Comment: Thanks Quentin! Could you tell me how to specify it in characters?

Comment: Err… no. I refer you back to the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: If you want to control the number of characters per line, do it when producing the HTML.

Comment: Oh.Sorry, I got it wrong... If I do it in css, could you tell me how to specify it?

Comment: `pre { width: 23cm; }` (note that cm isn't a great choice of unit for most situations). See also http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#CSS as you would be better off with an introductory CSS guide then a single example.